# If I want to re-review, should I open new question or edit old one?

Tags: discussion, iterative-review

I have a question here: [Tic Tac Toe game in Haskell](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/88497/tic-tac-toe-game-in-haskell/88500?noredirect=1#comment160230_88500)

I have followed the advices and edited the code, now I want a review for new version of the code.

It is doing the essentially same thing, but it is 80% or so different from previous code.

Should I open a new question or edit the old one?

Comment: You might want to wait a while to see if you get another review on the current implementation.